MCMCglmm predictions with two response variables (and prior)
I am currently in the process of running an MCMCglmm in R using the below code.
prior_tri=list(R = list(V = diag(c(1,1,0.0001),2,2), nu = 1.002, fix = 2),
               G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 2)))

mcmc_tri60=MCMCglmm(cbind(scale(y1),scale(y2))~(trait-1)+
                      at.level(trait, c("y1")):diel +
                      at.level(trait, c("y1")):poly(week,3) + 
                      at.level(trait, c("y2")):diel +
                      at.level(trait, c("y2")):poly(week,3) +
                      trait:scale(dl) +
                      trait:sex +
                      trait:type+
                      trait:Release_year,
                    random =~ us(trait):tag_id,
                    rcov =~ us(trait):units,
                    family = c("gaussian","gaussian"),
                    prior = prior_tri,
                    nitt= 1000000,
                    burnin=50000,
                    thin=200, 
                    verbose = TRUE,
                    pr = TRUE,
                    pl = TRUE,
                    trunc = TRUE,
                    data = comb2)



I have two questions:

can someone confirm I set my prior correctly (it´s meant to be un-informative)

I am trying to make predictions based on this model, however I struggle to find information on how to do so (especially with 2 response variables). If someone knows how to run predictions in a model similar to mine (see below for a summary of my attempts) or knows of resources that might be helpful, I would much appreciate your input!


I tried using a simple
predict(mcmc_tri60, ...)
(http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf). However, this provides me with one prediction total, not one prediction per response variable (y1, y2).
I also written a "newdata" df as:

dummy=expand.grid(week=seq(0,52, by = 1),tag_id = unique(comb2$tag_id),Release_year=1,sex = "male", diel = "day", dl = 35, type = "SR", y2= 5.8)

to fix my y2 and get a prediction for y1; but I get the error:
Error: object 'y1' not found, unless I add , y1=  unique(comb2$y1) and run predict(mcmc_tri60,newdata=dummy,type="response",se=TRUE), which then produces another error (leading me to believe this is not the correct approach).
I have encountered this post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2015q3/023759.html and associated posts, however, the information provided in there is not enough for me to be able to understand how to run the predictions by myself..
Thanks for your input!

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rest?Julia?R? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
